# Expansion of string - character and occurrence of each character

Tags: string

I want to expand the string like below, but without using the extra space..

```
  a5b1c0d5a1a1
```

And result should be..

```
  aaaaabaa
```

I am stuck here. How to do it without extra space?

Comment: expand it how? what language?

Comment: I edited the question. Any language C/Java is fine. I don't want the code. Just the logic.

Comment: Ok, I'm completely stuck. As I am not supposed to use a new temporory string, how would I write it, given that aaaaa will already overwrite b1c.

Comment: Are you sure "no temporary string" means you have to use the input string to store the output, rather than just not using intermediate strings?  I mean, the result isn't necessarily temporary.  And how would such an algorithm handle e.g. "a5a5"?  And who will hire me if I come up with an answer to your question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would read each char, check is is letter, than take the next char, check if its a number, than just add to the resulting string the letter  times.

In your example, The first thing I would read is a, a is a letter, so read the next, check if its a number, it is. So append to a resulting string five a's.

Use a loop  times to append letter, for example.

**UPDATE**

Explaning my comment better.

So you're looping through the string.

index 0 you have the 'a'. So you read a letter, then you expect to get a number, which is 5.

I divide now the string in to other string. The first one will have everything until a, which in this case is only a.

The second one will have everything after the number, in this case 5, which will be b1c0d5a1a1

So take the first string, concatenate with the 4 (5-1, you already have the first a) an then concatenate with the rest of the string.

```
string = b1c0d5a1a1
string = substring(0,1) + "aaaa" + substring(1,stringsize-1);
```

In the cases like 0, you can play around with the substring indexes so you can remove the letter, instead of adding some more.

Comment: But I don't have to use a new result string, that's the problem.

Comment: @karate_kid - If you're doing it in Java you *do* have to use a new string.

Comment: @karate_kid You're saying u can't create one or is mandatory that you do it in the same string you're reading?

Comment: I am not supposed to use the extra space. I mean if I can use an extra space, then it's a very simple problem!

Comment: You can use substrings then. 

Read the first letter is an a, read the second is a number, is 5, The you so a substring in the a index (wich will be only a), and another starting from the next letter after 5, wich will be b. 

so take the substring, concanate with four more a's (5-1) you already have that one) and concatenate the string with the letters after that.

Comment: But then what? How to substitue it in 1st string without overwriting?

Comment: in certain languages (e.g. Java and C#), string is immutable and thus prohibits itself from being modified in-place.